# EditText не отображает ввод. Введенный текст становится видно только после скрытия клавиатуры

Tags: java, android

На экране располагаются 8 EditText. Они идут снизу вверх по порядку. После переноса проекта на другой компьютер, где установлена последняя версия Android studio, у последних двух EditText перестал отображаться текст при вводе. До переноса на другой пк, все отлично работало и проблемы не было. Код я никоим образом не менял.

На обрезанном скриншоте видно, что ввод происходит, но как бы под EditText, а сам текст можно увидеть только после сворачивания клавиатуры или переключения на другое поле EditText.[image: Стрелочкой указал, что ввод происходит]

В приложении имеется "Темная тема", но данная проблема никак не связанна со сменой цветов.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pnrasp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="132dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"
        android:text="@string/pnrasp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson1pn"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/lesson1pn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pnrasp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson2pn"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lesson2pn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson1pn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson3pn"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lesson3pn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson2pn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson4pn"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lesson4pn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson3pn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson5pn"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lesson5pn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson4pn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson6pn"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lesson6pn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson5pn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson7pn"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lesson7pn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson6pn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lesson8pn"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lesson8pn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson7pn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pnbackButton"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pn"
        android:text="@string/backButtonPn"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson7pn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pnrasp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson1pn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint3"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson2pn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint4"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson3pn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint5"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson4pn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint6"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson5pn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint7"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson6pn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint8"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lesson7pn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showbtntext"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pn"
        android:text="@string/showbtntext"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/savebtntext"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pn"
        android:text="@string/savebtntext"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java:

```
public class PnDay extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private SoundPool mSound;
    private SoundPool mSound2;
    private int mMelody=1;

    EditText[] editTexts;
    TextView[] lessons;
    TextView pnrasp;
    Button savebtntext, showbtn, pnbackbutton;

    SharedPreferences sPref;
    int x = 0;
    ConstraintLayout ConstLay;

    final String[] SAVED_TEXT = {
            "saved_text",
            "saved_text2",
            "saved_text3",
            "saved_text4",
            "saved_text5",
            "saved_text6",
            "saved_text7",
            "saved_text8"};



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pnday);

        mSound = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        mSound.load(this, R.raw.click, 1);
        mSound2 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        mSound2.load(this, R.raw.clicksch, 1);

        //кнопка выхода из активности
        pnbackbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pnbackButton);
        pnbackbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PnDay.this, SelectWeekDay.class);
                    intent.putExtra("x",x);
                    startActivity(intent);finish();
                    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    mSound.play(mMelody,1,1,1,0,1);
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });


        editTexts = new EditText[]{
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1),
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2),
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3),
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4),
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5),
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6),
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7),
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8)};

        lessons = new TextView[]{
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lesson1pn),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lesson2pn),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lesson3pn),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lesson4pn),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lesson5pn),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lesson6pn),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lesson7pn),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lesson8pn)};



        //кнопка "настроить"
        showbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showbtntext);
        showbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                savebtntext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for(EditText editText : editTexts){
                    editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                for(TextView lesson : lessons){
                    lesson.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mSound2.play(mMelody,1,1,1,0,1);
            }
        });

        //кнопка "сохранить"
        savebtntext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtntext);
        savebtntext.setOnClickListener(this);

        ConstLay = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.ConstLay);
        pnrasp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pnrasp);


        //темная тема
        final Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
        x = arguments.getInt("x");

        loadText();
        checkX();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.savebtntext:
                saveText();
                showbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                savebtntext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                for(EditText editText : editTexts){
                    editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                for(TextView lesson : lessons){
                    lesson.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mSound.play(mMelody,1,1,1,0,1);
                loadText();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    void saveText() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length; i++)
        {
            ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT[i], editTexts[i].getText().toString());
        }
        ed.commit();
    }

    void loadText() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length; i++)
        {
            String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT[i], "");
            lessons[i].setText(savedText);
            editTexts[i].setText(savedText);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed (){
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(PnDay.this, SelectWeekDay.class);
            intent.putExtra("x",x);
            startActivity(intent);finish();
        }catch (Exception e){

        } //конец конструкции
    }

    void checkX(){
        if(x == 1){
            ConstLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1F1F1F"));
            pnrasp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));

            for(TextView lesson : lessons){
                lesson.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));
            }

            pnbackbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));
            showbtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));
            savebtntext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));

            for(EditText editText : editTexts){
                editText.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#AAAAAA"));
                editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));
                editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        }

        if(x == 0){
            ConstLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            pnrasp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

            for(TextView lesson : lessons){
                lesson.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }

            pnbackbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            showbtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            savebtntext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

            for(EditText editText : editTexts){
                editText.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#555555"));
                editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `android-studio` - метка связанная с вопросами по IDE!!! приложите код может какой-то, а то сложно помогать только по картинке

Comment: Подскажите, вам нужен код программы или код разметки?

Comment: это нужно не мне а вам)) вы ведь хотите чтобы вам помогли? так вот добавьте разметку и класс активности

Comment: Не понятно по скриншоту: в 7 поле нет текста? И уточните где запускаете, на реальном устройстве или эмуляторе? И мне кажется `invisible` лучше не использовать.

Comment: Запускаю на реальном устройстве. Ситуация, если честно странная. Я сейчас тот же код скопировал в новый проект и там все нормально работает. В поле 7 текст "7.Предмет(Кабинет)" - это hint, а сам текст вводится почему-то за ним, стрелочка указывает на то место, где заканчивается текст, который я ввел

Comment: Debugger:
`W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
    endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение! Проблема была в строке из манифеста `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`
Как она повлияла на это, я без понятия. Если честно, сам бы не отказался от пояснений тех, кто разбирается.